# Get Outlook AddressBook Contacts folders in VSTO addIn

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

Am developing an Outlook VSTO AddIn wherein I need to get the list of folders inside the AddressBook using C# code (see below screenshot)[image: Address Book]

That is, here I need to get the list folder names and subfolder names like Contacts, Offline Global Address List, All Contacts, All Distribution Lists, etc.

i.e., the folders we get using
Outlook.SelectNamesDialog snd = 
Application.          Session.GetSelectNamesDialog();
snd.Display();

Note that now I have two accounts configured within my Outlook.

Thanks in advance!

_N

Answer (score 0):

Use `Namespace.AddressLists` collection.